# How to convert an image to byte array without converting its type to JPEG

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, windows-phone

I have an application written for windows phone platform which decrypts images. To test the application I have a code in windows classic (desktop) platform, which communicates with the windows phone app through a TCP connection. Now I have an image in the windows phone app which is decrypted and I want to verify if it is the same as the original image (before encryption). Using XMLSerialization I cannot send Image type on the TCP connection; so I convert it to bytes using this code:

```
BitmapImage bitmapImage = image.Source as BitmapImage;
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    WriteableBitmap btmMap = new WriteableBitmap(bitmapImage.PixelWidth, bitmapImage.PixelHeight);

    Extensions.SaveJpeg(btmMap, ms, bitmapImage.PixelWidth, bitmapImage.PixelHeight, 0, 100);

    bytes = ms.ToArray();
}
```

However, the bytes I get does not match the original image bytes because the image is coded into Jpeg. Even when at the test side I convert the original image to jpeg format the bytes does not match. However, when I sent the bytes to the WinPhone application and convert both to Jpeg they are equal. How can I get the bytes without converting the image to the Jpeg format?

Answer (score 0):

The bellow code works fine for me.

```
public static byte[] imageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image sourceImage)
    {
        System.IO.MemoryStream memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

        sourceImage.Save(memoryStream, sourceImage.RawFormat);

        return memoryStream.ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: Image class does not have Save method in Windows Phone platform.